# extract argument & return types from C function pointer with libclang

Tags: llvm-clang, libclang

I'm using libclang (API version 0.43) to parse a C header file. Is there a way to extract the argument & return type(s) from a function pointer definition, e.g.

```
int (*my_add_fn)(int, int);
```

I can get a cursor to `my_add_fn`, and can see some info (output from print statements on the right:

```
print(cursor.spelling)                    # my_add_fn
print(cursor.type.kind)                   # TypeKind.POINTER
print(cursor.type.get_pointee().kind)     # TypeKind.UNEXPOSED
print(cursor.type.get_pointee().spelling) # int (int, int)
```

But I can't get an iterator for the args (like I can for a regular function prototype), and I'd rather not resort to string-mangling the `spelling` property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
cursor.type.get_pointee().get_result()
cursor.type.get_pointee().get_canonical().argument_types()
```

Comment: It's better to provide some explanation of the code you are adding as an answer. It helps the questionnaire as well as someone else (if the same problem occurs for someone else)